# Move from a <div> to another <div> on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I want my #logo-page div to move smoothly to #content div on scroll and also when clicked on FontAwesome icon. How do I do that using jQuery?

```html
<div class="english-container" id="logo-page">
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Mean Design.</h1>
        <img class="img-responsive" id="logo" src="MeanDesignLogo.png">
        <h3>ui/ux • web design • graphic design • illustration</h3>
    </div> <!-- title -->
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="english-container" ></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving from one div to another on click of a menu link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36761442/moving-from-one-div-to-another-on-click-of-a-menu-link)

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick on how to do that at this page:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Here are two demos:

https://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate_smoothscroll

This is the example of the second demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){
   
        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

```css
body, html, .main {
    height: 100%;
}

section {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#section2">Click Me to Smooth Scroll to Section 2 Below</a>

<div class="main">
  <section></section>
</div>

<div class="main" id="section2">
  <section style="background-color:blue"></section>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You guys completely ignored his question. His question was he wants to scroll from one div to another div when **on scroll** not **on click**.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
     document.querySelector('#mission').scrollIntoView({
         behavior: 'smooth'
     });
})
```

This will help if you want to scroll to the div with the id name "mission"

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code for scrolling smoothly to `#logo-page` div on click of `.fa-arrow-circle-down`:

```
$(".fa-arrow-circle-down").on("click", function(e){
  $("html, body").animate({'scrollTop': $("#logo-page").offset().top }, 1000 );
});//click
```