# Make an image link to another part of the page (one page scrolling site)

Tags: html, css

I want to have an image hotspot that links the user to another section of a one page scrolling site. It works so far but you can only click on the text over the image, how can I make it so the whole image is a link?

```
<div class="quarter-column">
<div class="welcome_square">
    <img src="/pageassets/freshers2016/info.jpg" alt="" />
    <a href="#info"><h2>NEED TO KNOW</h2></a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix" id="page2">
<a id="info" class="smooth"></a>
<div class="full-column" id="tiles">
<h2>NEED TO KNOW</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can put the `welcome_square` inside the `a`. or if only the image. u can also put the `img` inside the `a`

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/36761714/5383669 it will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need put `img` element into `a` link element, check this:

```
<div class="quarter-column">
 <div class="welcome_square">
  <a href="#info">
   <img src="/pageassets/freshers2016/info.jpg" alt="" /> <!-- <img/> inner <a/> link element -->
   <h2>NEED TO KNOW</h2>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix" id="page2">
 <a id="info" class="smooth">
  <div class="full-column" id="tiles">
   <h2>NEED TO KNOW</h2>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
```